# When a non-vectored interrupt occurs,does the processor ever look up the vector table ?

Tags: vector, interrupt, interrupt-handling, microprocessors

When a *non-vectored* interrupt occurs,does the processor ever look up the *vector table* ?

Talking of 8085 , is it different ?

Comment: What CPU are you talking about before `talking of 8085`? How about reading its documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**, the processor doesn't look up the vector table. It looks up the table during vectored interrupts.